# Counting elements from two columns/lists and stack the results from each list in a bar chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, count, bar-chart

So I have two lists with different size and containing some of the same and different words/elements:

```
list1 = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "blue", "green", "pink", "red"]
list2 = ["black", "black", "yellow", "red", "blue", "pink", "pink", "red", "purple", "white", "red", "orange", "red", "brown", "brown"]
```

If I wish to count how many of each words there is in each list and combined I say:

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_total = list1 + list2

c1 = Counter(list1)
c2 = Counter(list2)
c_all = Counter(list_total)
```

The resulting output (if printing the c's) is then:

```
Counter({'blue': 2, 'yellow': 2, 'red': 2, 'pink': 1, 'green': 1})
Counter({'red': 4, 'pink': 2, 'brown': 2, 'black': 2, 'blue': 1, 'purple': 1, 'yellow': 1, 'orange': 1, 'white': 1})
Counter({'red': 6, 'blue': 3, 'pink': 3, 'yellow': 3, 'brown': 2, 'black': 2, 'purple': 1, 'green': 1, 'orange': 1, 'white': 1})
```

So in principle I could just plot the `list_all` list and I would get a bar chart starting with the most frequent word from the left to the least frequent word in the right of the chart.

For that I would probably just use:

```
labels_total, values_total = zip(*Counter(list_total).most_common())
indexes = np.arange(len(labels_total))
plt.bar(indexes, values_total)
plt.show()
```

But I would like the two lists (not the combined list) to be stacked, so one can see from which list the most words comes from etc.

And this is where I'm stuck. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. First of all the two lists don't have the same number of words, and secondly some words are not even shared. So in this case `list1` would have `blue` as `index = 0` since that is the most frequent word in that list, but `list2` will have `red` as `index = 0` since that is the most frequent word in that list. So when trying to stack these `red` will just be added to `blue` since they have the same index - and that is of course wrong.
On the other hand, the two lists doesn't even have the same words, so the size (index number) when counting everything is not the same either, since `list1` only have 5 different words, while `list2` have 9. So you can't really stack them in a bar chart unless the dimensions are the same.

So I'm kind of lost right now. I can extend the low-dimension list via the `.extend` function by adding some zero entries (just as an example), but the ordering is still wrong since they will just be added/extended to the end of the list.

The code combined:

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "blue", "green", "pink", "red"]
list2 = ["black", "black", "yellow", "red", "blue", "pink", "pink", "red", "purple", "white", "red", "orange", "red", "brown", "brown"]
list_total = list1 + list2

c1 = Counter(list1)
c2 = Counter(list2)
c_all = Counter(list_total)

labels_total, values_total = zip(*Counter(list_total).most_common())
indexes = np.arange(len(labels_total))
plt.bar(indexes, values_total)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 l1_counter = []
 l2_counter = []
 for each in c_all.most_common():
 ...     l1_counter.append(c1.get(each[0],0))
 ...     l2_counter.append(c2.get(each[0],0))`
```

Then you can do something like [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) ?

Why it works - There were 2 problems at hand.

1. There may be different colors in the 2 lists,
2. The order according to frequency had to be maintained.

Now, **c_all** is a dictionary and iterating over it would not have given the keys in order which are displayed by **Counter**, hence, it became imperative to iterate over **c_all.most_common()**. Secondly, to make sure that we accounted for all colors I looked into both **c1 and c2** for keys in **c_all**. The **get** function of **dict** returns **None** if the key is not found else it returns the value stored against the key.

```
c1.get(each[0],0)
```

Here, it becomes an **OR** condition wherein if **None** is found for a key, then the other value in parantheses is assigned. In simple words, if a color was not present in a list, I assign 0 to the list_counter for that color, thereby it does not show up in stacked chart.

For your particular example -

```
c1
Counter({'blue': 2, 'yellow': 2, 'red': 2, 'pink': 1, 'green': 1})
c2
Counter({'red': 4, 'pink': 2, 'brown': 2, 'black': 2, 'blue': 1, 'purple': 1, 'yellow': 1, 'orange': 1, 'white': 1})
c_all
Counter({'red': 6, 'blue': 3, 'pink': 3, 'yellow': 3, 'brown': 2, 'black': 2, 'purple': 1, 'green': 1, 'orange': 1, 'white': 1})
l1_counter
[2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
l2_counter
[4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Now you may better connect what is going on. For a color displayed in **c_all**(in order), I just stacked up colors in each list, assigning 0 if the color was not found. Hope this helps.

You can read more about the **get** function or dict in general [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: I know one shouldn't thank people in replies, but this really worked like a charm. Thank you. However, I'm really not quite sure what it actually does that makes it work. Could you maybe enlighten?

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "blue", "green", "pink", "red"]
list2 = ["black", "black", "yellow", "red", "blue", "pink", "pink", "red", "purple", "white", "red", "orange", "red", "brown", "brown"]

listall = list1+list2
unique = list(set(listall))

counts1 = np.array([list1.count(item) for item in unique])
counts2 = np.array([list2.count(item) for item in unique])
countsall = counts1+counts2
inx = np.argsort(countsall)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(range(len(countsall)), counts1[inx][::-1], label="list1")
ax.bar(range(len(countsall)), counts2[inx][::-1], bottom=counts1[inx][::-1], label="list2")

ax.set_xticks(range(len(countsall)))
ax.set_xticklabels(([unique[i] for i in inx])[::-1])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]